# Elements in empty unordered_multiset

Tags: c++, stl

It's a strange question, but if I've deleted elements from unordered_multiset a and then try to print its elements:

```
for (std::unordered_multiset<int>::const_iterator i(a.begin()), end(a.end()); i != end; ++i)    
{
   std::cout << "It's here" <<"\n"; 
   std::cout << *i <<"\n";  
}
```

So, is it ok, if this loop doesn't not work, I mean even "It's here" wasn't printed? How behaves an empty multiset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the set is empty then `begin() == end()` is true and the loop is never entered.